# Is there a Google Sheets formula to produce a "conditional" sum spanning multiple columns of a spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, formula

I have a Spreadsheet that Lists total items by specific people...

[image: pic1]

I am trying to set up a system where you can select certain people (by using checkboxes), and it lists the total number of items for the selected people....

[image: pic2]

Which Outputs:

[image: pic3]

I currently have it set up so that the people that you mark the checkbox for get put in a vertical column....
(I tried this to help with different formula parameters, but don't know if I really need to)

Alex
Charlie
Erika

From what I can tell `=DSUM` is closest to what I am trying to do, but I don't now the proper syntax for what I am trying, or if I should restructure my data to work better with this formula.

Comment: When I edit the question, the preview shows 3 nice tables, but when I submit only the middle table displays properly. I do not know why, sorry.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Formula:

`=SUMIF($B$2:$F$2, TRUE, B3:F3)`

#### Parameters:

`$B$2:$F$2` - location of the checkboxes

`TRUE` - will include in the sum if checkbox is ticked

`B3:F3` - range of the specific item

#### Note:

- Just drag the formula on all rows.

#### Output:

[image: output]

Or when using the transposed data:

#### Formula:

`=sumif($B$2:$B, TRUE, C2:C)`

#### Parameters:

`$B$2:$B` - location of the checkboxes

`TRUE` - will include in the sum if checkbox is ticked

`C2:C` - range of the specific item

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Just drag the formula on all columns.

Comment: I tried the first one and it says #REF! (Error Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 139. Actual: 1)

This is what I put so far: ={transpose('CG TEST'!C1:EK1),transpose(query(query({'CG TEST'!B4:EK406}, "select sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4), sum(Col5) where Col1 = TRUE"), "offset 1", 0))}


When I tried the second one it says : #VALUE! (Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY Parameter 2: TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'get' of undefined)

=query(query({B4:E406}, "select sum(Col2),sum(Col3), sum(Col4) where Col1 = TRUE"), "offset 1", 0)

Comment: Hi @seth_marie, since you have lots of columns and row and is impossible to list them all down, see my updated answer. The previous answer needs you to list all the columns down and would be a hassle if we used it on your case.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! @NaziA